# Mysql Error 2002 (HY000) on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

My boss update my computer to Snow Leopard, after the update we had a set back and deleted a few files/folders, since then is just nightmare after another one. I finally getting things back but I'm still having problems with MySQL. This is what I did:

1. Deleted ALL of mysql files/folders
2. Download and installed the packages mysql-5.1.45-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg
3. installed the Startup item and the preferences panel

After the above, I tried to start MySQL from the preferences panel without luck, and running the following command from Terminal

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

I get the following result

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I looked at some other post for possible solutions, but what they does not exactly fits my problem, so I cannot find a solution.

I'm new to all this and your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ERROR 2002 is usually caused by `mysqld` not running. Did you install and start the server? If so, then restart it as the socket may be missing for some reason.

Comment: thanks for the response, this lead me to the right solution

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the mysql socket file is located at `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` on OS X. Try:

```
ln -s /var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to my particular problem:

MySQL has a Preferences pane but I think it might not work on Snow Leopard. So the error I was getting is due to the fact the most likely installing just mysql it doesn't start the daemon. To start the deamon, I used launchd plist. If you do a Google search for Snow Leopard, MySQL and launchd, there are a number of articles out there.

A website that I found, had these instructions:

HiveLogic comes to the rescue with a preconfigured plist for launchd. (Or you could just set it up by hand or with Lingon)

Head to your temp directory and do the following. (Any directory will do – just make sure you delete the files afterwards. I have a ~/temp directory for this sort of stuff.)

```
curl -O http://hivelogic.com/downloads/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo mv com.mysql.mysqld.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

MySQL should now run on startup. To start it now (so you don’t need to reboot) do the following:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

If no errors are reported things are probably working.